# set active sheet is not opening the sheet in UI

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm new to the whole coding thing so I apologize in advance for any noobness.
I'm testing a simple snippet of code that I want to use in a few other functions but I cant seem to get it to work as expected and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. So essentially I want to be able to open a sheet tab in the UI, so that no matter what sheet is currently open and active, the sheet that opens for a user to use is the sheet defined.

```
    function activateDashboard(){

WorkBook.App.setActiveSheet(RECIPEBOOK.Dashboard);
Logger.log(WorkBook.ActiveSheet.getSheetName())// returns the currently open sheet name
Logger.log(WorkBook.App.setActiveSheet(RECIPEBOOK.Dashboard).getSheetName())//returns dashboard which is the sheet is want to open
   };
```

I'm not sure if `setActiveSheet` will even accomplish what I want. Maybe that's the reason it does not work or if its because im doing something wrong

Comment: [Here's the google apps script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)  This is the code that we use on the google-apps-script tag.  It doesn't look like you are using that code.

Comment: Workbook.app is just a variable for spreadsheet app.  I forgot to changed it back before I posted. I used both the variable, as well as spreadsheetapp with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the built in `SpreadsheetApp`. I am quite unfamiliar with `WorkBook.App` but it seems they have similar methods from the `SpreadsheetApp`.

#### Code:

```
function activateDashboard() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // returns the currently open sheet name - Should return "Sheet1"
  Logger.log(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetName());
  // sets "Sheet2" as active
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2'));
  // returns the currently open sheet name - Should return "Sheet2" after setActiveSheet
  Logger.log(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetName());
}
```

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample]

#### Log:

[image: log]

#### Output:

[image: output]